# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Entity Persistence

Tags: java, classpath, persistence.xml

I have a project with Persistence, and when i debug on server, it gives me this exception:

```
Advertencia: Exception or error caught in resource
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clibb/flower/data/entity/SupplyEntity
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.restlet.engine.resource.AnnotationUtils.addAnnotations(AnnotationUtils.java:136)
    at org.restlet.engine.resource.AnnotationUtils.getAnnotations(AnnotationUtils.java:231)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.getAnnotations(ServerResource.java:689)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.hasAnnotations(ServerResource.java:883)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.getVariants(ServerResource.java:794)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.getVariants(ServerResource.java:774)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doNegotiatedHandle(ServerResource.java:576)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doConditionalHandle(ServerResource.java:299)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.handle(ServerResource.java:846)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.handle(Finder.java:510)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:156)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:203)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:497)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:737)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:156)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:203)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:156)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:203)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:156)
    at org.restlet.engine.application.StatusFilter.doHandle(StatusFilter.java:151)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:203)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:156)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:203)
    at org.restlet.engine.ChainHelper.handle(ChainHelper.java:111)
    at org.restlet.engine.application.ApplicationHelper.handle(ApplicationHelper.java:72)
    at org.restlet.Application.handle(Application.java:388)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:156)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:203)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:497)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:737)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:156)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:203)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:497)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:737)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:156)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:203)
    at org.restlet.engine.ChainHelper.handle(ChainHelper.java:111)
    at org.restlet.Component.handle(Component.java:388)
    at org.restlet.Server.handle(Server.java:488)
    at org.restlet.engine.ServerHelper.handle(ServerHelper.java:71)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:150)
    at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:1028)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clibb.flower.data.entity.SupplyEntity
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
```

I don't get why it gives me this error, With some research I fonds post talking about it being the classpath that is incorrect, or it miss somthing, or that some libraries are missing.

I don't even know what classpath to add, and even les what libraries to add, and Where!

I have Three projects, web-backend, web-backend-sync, web-service.

web-service is the project that I test, SupplyEntity is in the web-backend.

I'm completly lost.

Comment: Is this `SupplyEntity` in a third party library (external jar)? Did you put all your external jars inside WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: I have Three projects, web-backend, web-backend-sync, web-service.

web-service is the project that I test, SupplyEntity is in the web-backend. I don't underestand what do you mean with put all my external jars inside WEBINF/lib folder? what externar jars?